# how to come back to function when ipywidgets button press

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipywidgets

Im trying to do the next example. My problem is that when i press one button I need to go back to function "index" so i can continue with what i was doing (on the next line, i dont want to begin all again), and enter one of the conditions: **if continues.on_click(clicked)** . How can i go back to where i left after pressing a button ?

```
import IPython.display 
import ipywidgets
import ipywidgets as widgets

def clicked(option):
    if option.description == "continue":
        print ('continue')
        return ('continue')
    elif option.description == "finish":
        print('finishhh')
        return ('finishhh')

def index():
    print ('hello')
    continues = ipywidgets.Button()
    finish = ipywidgets.Button()

    continues.description =  "continue"
    finish.description =  "finish"

    display(continues, finish)
    continues.on_click(clicked)
    finish.on_click(clicked)
    if continues.on_click(clicked) == "continue":
        print('here!')
    elif finish.on_click(clicked) == "finish":
        print('here2')

index()
```

Thanks.